# Multiuser system

Tags: system, multi-user

Hello i have a question,
i write a requirement specification.

there is a system, where more than one person interacts with,
and i want to describe what happens when one person quits the interaction.

I don't know how exactly a mulituser systems works, 
i guess the system creates an instance (?), and when the user finished it get closed again?

but the system as such still runs (for sure).

how can i discribe that ... issue correctly? ( does it work like i guessed?)

thanks in davance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that the system listen on two different things :

- a message (interaction) from one of the connected users
- a login message from a new user

This behavior is parametrized by the number of connected users. In the limit case where all connected users disconnect, the system does not wait anything from connected users, but keep listening on new connections.